# Executable size on MAC

Tags: macos, executable, lazarus

I somehow managed to produce a MAC executable of *half the usual size* using Lazarus, but nobody knows how. I've inspected the executable using `nm`, but found no relevant differences:

- exactly the same maximum address
- nearly exactly the same number of lines (123316 vs 123318)
- randomly chosen inspected lines were either the same or differed slightly in the address

I wonder how can I find out more. I have no idea about MAC and similarly for binary formats.

Comment: Fat binary vs single arch only?

Comment: I wonder if you're stripping the binary or subtracting debugging symbols?

Comment: @lmz No idea.... no idea what they are. How could I find out?

Comment: @maaartinus try the "file" command?

Comment: @lmz "Mach-0 executable i386" in both cases.

Comment: @Michael Dautermann I forgot to mention, that it can't be debugging symbols as they're always off. I inspected the settings after having produced this smaller file and found no difference. The next produced binary (without changing anything) was big again. A similar Linux binary is about as big as the small one.

Comment: I like lmz's comment.  If you type in "nm -arch x86_64" on both executables, I bet one is compiled for i386 only.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann You'd lose. Neither contains x86_64 code.

Comment: Did you read the hints at the [Lazarus wiki](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Faq#Why_are_the_generated_binaries_so_big.3F)? You might also try to use the shell command **strip** to remove symbols from your file.

Comment: @jwdietrich I've checked size hints just now... it's exactly what gets used. But stripping helped: The files were reduced from 20 MB and 40 MB to 16 MB (both resulted in the same size). I guess, I have to investigate what exactly strip does.

Comment: The man page of strip says: "strip removes or modifies the symbol table attached to the output of the assembler and link editor.  This is useful to save space after a program has been debugged and to limit dynamically bound symbols."

Comment: The Apple linker iirc does not strip all symbols, even when you tell it to.